# Adding values to a vector by index - improve speed

Tags: r, indexing

I have a matrix of indices and a vector of values which is as long as the number of rows in the matrix. I have an output vector which is the same length as the values, but all zeros.

For each entry c at position (i,j) in the matrix, I need to add values[i] to output[c] - that is, for each entry of the matrix, I must find the value of the output vector at that index and add to it the number in the values vector indexed by the row the matrix where the entry appears.

For instance, if values = [1,2,3,4] and mx_indices is

[1,1, 
2,2, 
3,3 
1,2]

Then the output should be [6, 8, 6, 0]

Here is my simple R code to attempt it:

```
# Example: values has 10 entries, and we have 100 types to compute
mx_indices <- matrix(floor(runif(1000)*10), ncol = 10, nrow=100)
values <- 1:100
output <- rep(0,10)
for(i in 1:length(values)){
    for(j in mx_indices[i,]){
        output[j] <- output[j] + values[i]
    }
}
```

It works, but is slow. I will be doing this repeatedly for a matrix that has lots of rows (half a million is the bare minimum) and for a long 'values' vector.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? Are there any obvious mistakes I am making?

Thanks

EDIT: I had errors in the example and my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
mx_indices <- matrix(sample(1:9, 1000, TRUE), ncol = 10, nrow=100)
values <- 1:100

rowSums(matrix(values[mx_indices], ncol=ncol(mx_indices)))
```

Comment: Hi Berry, thanks for the answer. I realised there were some errors in my question, I have tidied it up and tried your solution, but it doesn't give the right answer, as in the example.

Comment: Your examle has myindices with zeros - in R, there is no zeroth element of a vector. Code works fine here:  `values <- 1:4;  
mx_indices <- matrix(c(1,2,3,1, 1,2,3,2), ncol=2);  
mx_indices;  
values[mx_indices];  

rowSums(matrix(values[mx_indices], ncol=ncol(mx_indices)))
`

Comment: Oh, you reframed your question. I think I don't get what you want to do.